# Add a function in models.py or managers.py

Tags: django

I'd like to send an activation link to a new registered user. Should I write my function in my models.py or managers.py?

It's always confused to me to know where put the function, even after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them, models and managers are related to application data. Sending emails are related to the logic of your app: actions, decisions, answers ... so you should do this in a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/).

If you need to save time, you can use Django Registration as @karthikr suggests to you, this app is a good wrapper for reaching this aim.

I've assumed you need to send the link in the moment that the user has registered, but if you want to do this in other moment you can use a scheduled task: a django cron, an external python process or ...; that is up to you: your porpuse, the design of your app.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog](http://mirobetm.blogspot.com/2007/04/django-model-managers-do-not-repeat.html) could help you understand the use of managers better.

I would put the activation link in managers, because it would be easier to manage the various activities around it - resend activation link, validation, etc. It could be done with models too, but managers make it more modular.

[Django Registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cdef30dc0a91ed1968be17bb1e60da4/registration?at=default) is quitely widely used for registration - you could see how it is implemented there as well.

Comment: I think we can go as far as to say that using Django Registration is probably a better idea than implementing that on one's own!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can write your customized function in models.py but not sure about  manage.py .

I have used signal method in models.py to for mailservice facility.